# How do I compact and/or frame a json-ld document so that IRI values are expressed succinctly as well as keys?

Tags: json-ld, linked-data, skos

Given an original JSON-LD document like this example, which defines the `sources` for some `thing1`:

```
[
  {
  
    "@id": "https://example.com/thing1",
    "https://example.com/sources": [
      {
        "@id": "https://example.com/vocab/countries/EN"
      },
      {
        "@id": "https://example.com/vocab/countries/FR"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

(I'm simplifying quite a lot - in my real use-case this is larger and generated from RDF data. `ex:vocab/countries` is a SKOS `ConceptScheme` including `EN` and `FR` as `Concepts`)

I want to collapse it into something approximating what I'd use to express that in more normal JSON:

```
{
   "@id": "https://example.com/thing1",
   "sources": ["EN", "FR"]
}
```

I find I can use a context to collapse into name/values and shorten the names:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@version": 1.1,
    "ex": "https://example.com/",
    "sources": {
      "@id": "ex:sources",
      "@type": "@id"
    }
  },
  "@id": "ex:thing1",
  "sources": [
    "ex:vocab/countries/EN",
    "ex:vocab/countries/FR"
  ]
}
```

An important element is `"@type": "@id"` which collapses the source definitions from (a list of) objects into key/value pairs, and the enclosing context term maps `https://example.com/sources` to `sources`.

But I cannot find a way which seems to do the same on the values, so that they become `EN` and `FR` instead of `ex:vocab/countries/EN` and `ex:vocab/countries/FR`.  My experiments with adding `@base` and `@vocab` properties to the context don't appear to work like I expected them to.

I also need to do this in a scoped way, so that other properties besides `sources` can be defined which reference different vocabularies. For instance I might want to include `languages`, which could include terms from a vocabulary representing English, French, Gaelic, Breton, etc. In other words, I can't just set a global vocabulary or base for the entire document.

Can anyone tell me if this kind of transform is possible, and if so, how to achieve it?

JSON-LD Playground link [here](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-compacted&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fthing1%22%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsources%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%2Fcountries%2FEN%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%2Fcountries%2FFR%22%7D%5D%7D%5D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40version%22%3A1.1%2C%22ex%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2FFruit%22%2C%22fruit%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3AFruit%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%7B%7D%7D&context=%7B%22%40version%22%3A1.1%2C%22ex%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%2C%22sources%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3Asources%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the expected values of `sources` to `@vocab` instead of `@type` and use a scoped context to set the `@vocab` to use. For example:

```
{
  "@version": 1.1,
  "ex": "https://example.com/",
  "sources": {
    "@id": "ex:sources",
    "@type": "@vocab",
    "@context": {
      "@vocab": "https://example.com/vocab/countries/"
    }
  }
}
```

(playground [link](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-compacted&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fthing1%22%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsources%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%2Fcountries%2FEN%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%2Fcountries%2FFR%22%7D%5D%7D%5D&context=%7B%22%40version%22%3A1.1%2C%22ex%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%2C%22sources%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22ex%3Asources%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40vocab%22%2C%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvocab%2Fcountries%2F%22%7D%7D%7D)).

This says to treat the values of `playground` as vocabulary-relative IRIs, and sets the base of that vocabulary for those values. You should get the following:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@version": 1.1,
    "ex": "https://example.com/",
    "sources": {
      "@id": "ex:sources",
      "@type": "@vocab",
      "@context": {
        "@vocab": "https://example.com/vocab/countries/"
      }
    }
  },
  "@id": "ex:thing1",
  "sources": [
    "EN",
    "FR"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ah, this seems to do the job! In fact, I tried to do this in various ways already, but I must have got something subtly wrong. Although the high-level view of the specification for json-ld  seems to make sense, I find the details in it quite hard to make use of in practice.